# Alter shell script to look through a dynamic list of directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I currently have a script (connected to a GUI) that goes to a designated folder, gets a file, places it elsewhere. Works just fine.

```
# set up log in info.
HOST=$1
USER=$2
PASS=$3

#local file info
FROMDIR=$4
FROMFILE=$5

#remote file info
TODIR=$6
TOFILE=$7

#sent dir
SENTDIR=$FROMDIR/../sent

#log dir
DIRNAME=`/usr/bin/dirname $0`
LOGDIR=$DIRNAME/../log
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/$5.log


#####################################################
#
# move the file to the pickup folder 
#
#####################################################

if ! test -d $LOGDIR
then
    /usr/bin/mkdir $LOGDIR
fi



if  `/usr/bin/cp "$FROMDIR/$FROMFILE" "$TODIR/$TOFILE"`
then
    echo `date` >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Successfully copied file from $FROMDIR/$FROMFILE to $TODIR/$TOFILE" >> $LOGFILE
    exit 10;
else
    echo `date` >> $LOGFILE.failed
    echo "Colud not copy file from $FROMDIR/$FROMFILE to $TODIR/$TOFILE" >> $LOGFILE.failed
    exit 1;
fi
```

However, I now want to alter it to go through a list of sub-directories and bring the files over to one location.

Notes:
For this following, use this as reference:

```
/foo/sing/song
         /tommy
               /chicken
                     /in
                     /out
               /burger
                     /in
                     /out
               etc...
```

The sub-directories under /tommy will constantly be growing. I need to go into each folder's "/in" and bring the files over to /foo/sing/song (which should still work fine with my script).

I appreciate any help you can provide; I'm fairly new to shell scripting so wildcards and loops in this field are still a bit above me.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the first 3 parameters are useless (not used in the script)  right? (HOST, USER and PASS)

Comment: they are sometimes used... but in this case, no. But this gives the option of entering in FTP information in the GUI so that I can log in to an FTP folder and drop off files.

Comment: Still, the script does not use those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a one-liner:

```
cp -r /foo/sing/song/tommy/*/in/* /foo/sing/song
```

Wildcards like `*` are very easy to understand: it means *anything*. The `-r` is optional and is needed if only you have other directories in your `in` folders.